# Linux - count words with more than a certain length of characters

Tags: linux, grep, wc

i want to know how to count the number of words in a .txt file that has more than 5 characters, using *egrep* and *wc*. Please, be clear as i'm new to linux.

Comment: Have you tried some code? Where do you face difficulties?

Comment: Does it have to be with just those two?

Comment: @thanasisp only know how to count the words cat file.txt | wc -w, i'm having a problem filtering the length of the word

Comment: @ilkkachu according to my professor it has to contain egrep, but the wc is opcional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you mentioned your professor, I'm a bit worried we're doing your homework for you, but you can try:

```
egrep -wo '[[:alnum:]]{5,}' filename.txt | wc -w
```

This looks for spans of 5 or more alphanumeric characters in a row forming a word (`-w`), prints only the matches, each on its own line (`-o`) and then counts them with `wc -w`. (`wc -l` would also work in this case).

Change `[[:alnum:]]` to `[[:alpha:]]` if only letters should count.

If for some reason you want only to use egrep, you can call it twice, and have the second one count any line with anything in it.

```
egrep -wo '[[:alnum:]]{5,}' filename.txt | egrep -c '.'
```